# Tracking Contact Form 7 in Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-tag-manager, contact-form-7

I need to track two contact form events on tag manager, the forms are basically the same, the only difference is the purpose: one sends to WhatsApp (it opens in a popup) and the other sends an e-mail.

I'm using this tracking code as a listener:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener ( 'wpcf7mailsent', function ( event ) {
  window.dataLayer.push ({
     "event": "cf7mailsent",
     "cf7FormId": event.detail.contactFormId,
     "cf7Fields": event.detail.inputs
  })
});
</script>
```

But the event is just working with one form (the e-mail one), and the other is being ignored.

How to solve this?

Comment: can you confirm that both forms push the DL event? Also, do you happen to have limited the tag to fire once per pageview in GTM?

Comment: Where are you adding this code?

Comment: I reckon the pop-up is causing the problem...try to open your whatsapp form within the main page to see if it fires properly.